# Multiple "ServerName" per VHost?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, apache-2.2

In Apache2 is it possible to set multiple ServerNames in one VHost?

I want to setup a "wiki" vhost for an internal wiki.

My network has a ".lan" suffix.  How do I get Apache to answer both "wiki" and "wiki.lan" on the same vhost?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Use both the `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` directives in your virtualhost definition. You would do something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    Servername wiki.lan 
    ServerAlias wiki

    [...]

</Virtualhost>
```

See [Apache Docs – ServerAlias Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#serveralias).

Comment: Thats right!  I had forgotten about ServerAlias...

Comment: Does it make a difference which name is specified at ServerName and ServerAlias? Can it be exchanged?

Comment: ServerName is the one used when apache can not figure which host to use. E.g. when connecting using an IP address instead of a hostname.

Answer (score 39):

Add the other names with `ServerAlias`.

You can use any of those 2 formats or a mixture:

```
ServerAlias aaa.example.com bbb.example.com ccc.example.com

ServerAlias ddd.example.com
ServerAlias eee.example.com
ServerAlias fff.example.com
```

The directive is valid only in [VirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost) section.

See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#serveralias